# automate process of record being inserted into database table using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i'm new to asp.net. I am attempting to automate the insertion of a record into a database table every 1st or 2nd of the month.

The record i will be inserting would DateTime.Now for which ever day the record is inserted.

I've seen lots on how to do this through using views and forms but i am not sure how this would be done without these and solely by automation in the application.

My Model and controller currently are as follows:

**Reports Model**

```
namespace CRMReporting.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Reports
    {
        public int Report_ID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Reports Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Report_ID,Date")] Reports reports)
    {
        var day = DateTime.Now.Day;

        if (day == 1||day == 2)
        {
            reports.Date = DateTime.Now;
            db.Reports.Add(reports);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Reports.Add(reports);
        }

        return View(reports);
    }
```

The report_id field for the database table is an auto-increment field

Thanks guys

Comment: Why you did not write `db.SaveChanges()` after both of inserts?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net works by request/response and nothing will happen automatically until you hava a timer. You can save data by users requests. If you want this happens only one time at the day:

```
    var day = DateTime.Now.Day;
    // To avoid multiple insertion save the last insert date:
    if (day == 1||day == 2 && DateTime.Now.Date != (DateTime)Application["last_Saved"])
    {
        reports.Date = DateTime.Now;
        db.Reports.Add(reports);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Application["last_Saved"] = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
```

But if no user requests at the day you will not have insert.

And as an idea it seems you have a bad database design, And you can find a better way.